# Unable to Change Bootstrap Toggle Background

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, jekyll

I moved my site from Wordpress to Jekyll and used bootstrap to frame it. On the mobile view, I am unable to change the change the transparent background to something with opacity or color. Here's my site: http://misllc.com. Any help/suggestions would be great appreciated.

Comment: Can you please tell us which html element is targeted ?

Comment: @DavidJacquel I think that's the trouble I'm having... I can't seem to find it. :-/ Just wondering if anyone has had a similar problem.

Comment: I think you're missing the `media query` on your stylesheet. Have you checked it?

Comment: I found this great website that will do it for me: http://work.smarchal.com/twbscolor/css/e74c3cc0392becf0f1ffbbbc0